# Why is each grade inputted the same no matter what the program defines including the average?

Tags: python

The program is as follows: Write a program that asks the user to input 5 test scores. The program should display a letter grade for each score and the average test score.

I am having issues with my output showing me a letter grade of the first inputted grade for every grade including the average. My numeric average is also being outputted as a letter grade, but it gives the correct average letter for that rather than the correct numeric result for the grade. I am in a low level coding class, therefore the program must be written in this format.

Here is the code:

```
a=float(input("Enter score 1:"))
b=float(input("Enter score 2:"))
c=float(input("Enter score 3:"))
d=float(input("Enter score 4:"))
e=float(input("Enter score 5:"))
def determine_grade(a,b,c,d,e):
    num=a
    if(num<=100 and num>=90):
        grade='A'
    elif(num<=89 and num>=80):
        grade='B'
    elif(num<=79 and num>=70):
        grade='C'
    elif(num<=69 and num>=60):
        grade='D'
    else:
        grade='F'
    return grade

def calc_average(a,b,c,d,e):
    mean=(a+b+c+d+e)//5
    if mean<=100 and mean>=90:
        avggrade='A'
    elif(mean<=89 and mean>=80):
        avggrade='B'
    elif(mean<=79 and mean>=70):
        avggrade='C'
    elif(mean<=69 and mean>=60):
        avggrade='D'
    else:
        avggrade='F'
    return avggrade

grade=determine_grade(a,b,c,d,e)
avggrade=determine_grade(a,b,c,d,e)
mean=calc_average(a,b,c,d,e)
determine_grade(a,b,c,d,e)
calc_average(a,b,c,d,e)
print("Score           Numeric Grade   Letter Grade")
print("--------------------------------------------")
print("Score 1:         ",a,"            ",grade)
print("Score 2:         ",b,"            ",grade)
print("Score 3:         ",c,"            ",grade)
print("Score 4:         ",d,"            ",grade)
print("Score 5:         ",e,"            ",grade)
print("--------------------------------------------")
print("Average Score:   ",mean,"            ",avggrade)
```

Whenever I put in (a):

```
num=a,b,c,d,e
```

in place of what is shown in the code, I get a syntax error saying:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

If I don't do what has been shown in (a), my output is this:

```
Enter score 1:90
Enter score 2:88
Enter score 3:76
Enter score 4:68
Enter score 5:40
Score           Numeric Grade   Letter Grade
--------------------------------------------
Score 1:          90.0              A
Score 2:          88.0              A
Score 3:          76.0              A
Score 4:          68.0              A
Score 5:          40.0              A
--------------------------------------------
Average Score:    C              A
```

Comment: Hey Josh, why does `determine_grade` use five arguments if you only use the `a` variable in it? You should probably call that function five times instead of writing unused arguments

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there's some things to talk about here. First, I suggest that you experiment a bit more with simpler functions to properly get used to them. When you define `determine_grade(a,b,c,d,e)` your function will expect to find a,b,c,d,e arguments inside the function, but if you read it again, you'll notice that you only mention `a`. This means when you call `grade=determine_grade(a,b,c,d,e)` you're only calculating a's grade, and that's why you have the same grade for everyone (if you type `grade` with your code you'll notice it will output `'A'`.

Another way to write a function that does exactly what you're looking for is this:

```
def determine_grade(score):
    num=score
    if(num<=100 and num>=90):
        grade='A'
    elif(num<=89 and num>=80):
        grade='B'
    elif(num<=79 and num>=70):
        grade='C'
    elif(num<=69 and num>=60):
        grade='D'
    else:
        grade='F'
    return grade
```

You input a score (that can be a,b,c,d or e) and it calculates a grade. If you want to get everyone's grade, then you can do something like this:

```
grades=[]
for i in [a,b,c,d,e]:
    grades.append(determine_grade(i))
```

This will bring a list with all grades.

Then, if you want the average grade, it's better to calculate the average score, so you can use your same function to get the grade:

```
mean_score=np.array([a,b,c]).mean()
mean_grade(determine_grade(mean_score)
```

Doing this you'll have all the information you need with way less lines of code (And you can make it even more efficient using list comprehensions, but that's a bit more advanced).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, your functions should be rewritten to accept a single input and then called several times. Also, your program is a classic case of something that should be DRYed up (Don't Repeat Yourself). Instead of manually typing `a = input()`, `b = input()` why not consider just tossing all these inputs into a list (perhaps with some string formatting on your prompt like my code). Below is a program that can easily be adjusted to accept arbitrary amounts of inputs:

```
input_scores = [] # make our list
scores_input = 5 # tell the program we have 5 scores to record
for input_count in range(1, scores_input + 1):
    input_scores.append(float(input("Enter score {}:".format(input_count))))

def determine_grade(percent): # single input
    if 90 <= percent <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= percent <= 89:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= percent <= 79:
        grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= percent <= 69:
        grade = 'D'
    else:
        grade = 'F'
    return grade # single output

def calc_average(local_score_list): # expects the list we made earlier (many inputs)
    mean = sum(local_score_list) // len(local_score_list)
    if 90 <= mean <= 100:
        average_grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= mean <= 89:
        average_grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= mean <= 79:
        average_grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= mean <= 69:
        average_grade = 'D'
    else:
        average_grade = 'F'
    return mean, average_grade # have our function return both values, since it calculated them both anyways

compiled_scores = []
for test_score in input_scores:
    letter_grade = determine_grade(test_score) # calling our single input/output function many times in a for loop
    compiled_scores.append((test_score, letter_grade)) # creating a tuple so each letter and percent is stored together

mean_percent, mean_letter_grade = calc_average(input_scores) # decompile both values from our function
print("Score           Numeric Grade   Letter Grade")
print("--------------------------------------------")
# now we iterate through all the scores made and print them
for count, result_tuple in enumerate(compiled_scores, 1): # just print the scores in a loop
    print("Score {}:         ".format(count), result_tuple[0], "            ", result_tuple[1])

print("--------------------------------------------")
print("Average Score:   ", mean_percent, "            ", mean_letter_grade)
```

You can see that we condensed our `input()` lines -> a single line, and condensed the print statements as well! Now our program can take, say, 30 scores and work just as well!!! (This is huge)!! And all that is required to change is the number `5` at the top of our script -> `30`. No longer will we have to type `print('this')` or `input('that')`! Our script will automatically adjust because we made it able to scale with our list.

My test case (using same numbers from your post):

```
Enter score 1:90
Enter score 2:88
Enter score 3:76
Enter score 4:68
Enter score 5:40
Score           Numeric Grade   Letter Grade
--------------------------------------------
Score 1:          90.0              A
Score 2:          88.0              B
Score 3:          76.0              C
Score 4:          68.0              D
Score 5:          40.0              F
--------------------------------------------
Average Score:    72.4              C
```

Let me know if you need further clarification on something I posted!